# android studio, problem with "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table:"

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I need to read rows from table "levels" in the database.
The db will be copied from assets to databases folder at the first launch of the app.
When i try to see inside the folder "databases" thats what there is [inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmvTy.png).

If i save all files in databases folder on my desktop and i open the dbarkanoid on "db browser for sqlite" the "levels" table not exist.

If i save only dbarkanoid in databases folder on my desktop and i open the dbarkanoid on "db browser for sqlite" the "levels" table exist.

So ,of course ,  if i delete shm and wal file from databases the app work fine and find the "levels" table without problems.

Thats, the method for the copy of the db from assets:

```
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myInput.close();
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();

    }
```